# Rearranging Formulas - How does this formula turn into this one.

Tags: physics

How does $ \Delta E_t = m\times c \times \Delta \Theta $
 rearrange into 
$ \Delta \Theta =\frac{\Delta E_t} {m  \times c }  $

Would prefer if you could break it down step by step if possible.

Comment: Both sides are divided by $m\times c$, that's all.

Comment: Oh I see now thanks